# How to set a maximum number of files for imagePicker in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

let me explain
How can I set a maximum number of files to pick for filepicker so that I can limit the pick of file
so it does not overload the server.

Comment: I will be thankful if anyone solve this for me

Answer (score 4):

`imagePicker` does not allow selecting a specific count. I don't think Java does either without developing your own custom gallery. `imagePicker` just calls to [platform code](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/174f140651e9ca9c958f2ae75960684c27772a07/packages/image_picker/image_picker/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerDelegate.java#L332) in any case and if that platform doesn't support I think we're out of luck.

One thing you can do is allow the user to pick as many images as they want (so just regular multi image pick) but then just `take` however many you need then show a toast that says only count number of photos were used. This feels like a decent trade off.

Comment: I have found a solution fir that 
I have posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by this block of code

```
Future galleryImage() async {
if (images.length == 0 || images.length < 4) {
  var pics = await ImagePicker().pickMultiImage(imageQuality: 10);
  if (pics != null && pics.length < 5) {
    photos = pics;
    pics.forEach((element) {
      images.add(File(element.path));
      update();
      print('length: ${images.length}');
    });
    update();
  }
```